# Azure Data Factory Not Copying all JSON fields when Copying to Azure SQLDB

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from JSON file to Azure SQLDB. The data in JSON looks like the following:

[image]

The data that is sent to Azure SQLDB looks like the following:

[image]

You will notice the Businessday, Finaldeadlineday, CommentaryWriter, and TemplateCode aren't copied to the Azure SQLDB

Can someoone explain why this is? And how to get to copy all the fields from the JSON file to Azure SQLDB please

Comment: ...why are you using `nvarchar(max)` for `datetime` fields?

Comment: Those missing fields are all contained within a _nested_ JSON array-of-objects (`Template`) - importing that will require you to specify how it should be mapped to your SQL Server tables. For example, what should happen if the `Template` array contains 2 or more objects?

Comment: Hi @Dai, you're right. The problem is a mapping issue. Thank yoiu

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your required output, you need to use **Collection reference** and **Advanced editor** in the copy activity mapping.

[image]

Here, you can remove the extra columns and give the required data types for the target columns.

**Result table:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, the problem is, if I use the Collection reference with the Advanced editor, I I will get the data from fields under ```$['Template']```, but I will get nulls from all the other fields. Is there a way of just applying the Collecton reference to individual fields?

Comment: No, to get like that, you need to use flatten transformation in the dataflow. In Copy activity it might not be possible.